# shadow to layout by 100% radius

Tags: android, shadow

I want add shadow to layouts like below image :

http://s9.picofile.com/file/8321463292/android.png

I do not want use android:elevation, because not working for android 4.3

Also, I use these libraries but not work correct for me :

```
https://github.com/loopeer/shadow
https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout
https://github.com/Devlight/ShadowLayout
https://github.com/harjot-oberai/MaterialShadows
https://github.com/xuehuayous/Android-ShadowView
```

How i can set shadow to layouts like top image ? ( smooth, 100% radius and colorful)

Thank you

Comment: `... because not working for android 4.3` I'm sure that using the support library comes in handy.

Comment: @KlingKlang my device is galaxy s3 but not work elevation on this device

Comment: ...?! why should an Android device work in a different way from all others?

Comment: @Kling Klang you never know what the vendors do ;)

Comment: I know they use custom themes. And maybe custom launchers as well. If this is the problem, your app would fail showing a shadow on every device with a different launcher or theme.

Comment: @KlingKlang , NO, on galaxy S8 work correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two suggestions to make shadow as per your requirement

> you can use **9-patch image**, may be this [link](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/) will help you to create 9-patch with shadow

alternate

> solution is to make gradient and set background to your button view.

Comment: Thank you, but 9-patch is not smooth

Comment: @AbarNew `... 9-patch is not smooth` this is true only in your fantasy.